# "event" in Javascript is deprecated and I cannot use "preventDefault()"

Tags: javascript, forms, event-handling, dom-events, preventdefault

I am trying to use the `event.preventDefault()` method but I am continuously receiving error. It says that `event` has been **deprecated**.

I am making a Firebase SignUp form and I want to prevent the form from Submitting.

Here is the complete code.

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import getFirebase from "../../firebase"
import useInput from "./useInput"

const SignUpForm = () => {
  const firebaseInstance = getFirebase()
  const email = useInput("")
  const password = useInput("")

  const signUp = async () => {
        event.preventDefault()
    try {
      if (firebaseInstance) {
        const user = await firebaseInstance
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
        console.log("user", user)
        alert(`Welcome ${email.value}!`)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error)
      alert(error.message)
    }
  }
event.preventDefault()
  return (
    <FormWrapper onSubmit={() => signUp()}>
      <Title>Sign up</Title>
      <Input placeholder="Email" {...email} />
      <Input placeholder="Password" type="password" {...password} />
      <Button type="submit">Sign up</Button>
    </FormWrapper>
  )
}

export default SignUpForm
```

And the **useInput** code:

```
import { useState } from "react"

const useInput = initialValue => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange,
  }
}

export default useInput
```

Comment: it's not clear how `FormWrapper` uses its `onSubmit` prop, but assuming it's an event handler the typical pattern (certainly with native DOM events) is for it to be passed the event object as a function parameter. So you would pass the prop as `onSubmit={signUp}` and then have `signUp = async (event) => { event.preventDefault(); /* rest of code */ };`

Comment: In your form submit handler, you use `event.preventDefault()`, but you never pass an `event` into that function. Change this line: `<FormWrapper onSubmit={(event) => signUp(event)}>` (note the added event object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What that warning means is that the *global variable* `window.event` is deprecated. You can still access the event associated with an event handler, you just have to go about it the proper way - by using the parameter from the handler callback.

Change

```
<FormWrapper onSubmit={() => signUp()}>
```

to

```
<FormWrapper onSubmit={signUp}>
```

and then `signUp`'s first parameter will be the event, and you'll be able to use it and call `preventDefault` on it as you're trying.

```
const signUp = async (event) => {
```

But don't put `event.preventDefault()` in your functional component's main body - that is, it shouldn't be here:

```
event.preventDefault()
  return (
    ...
```

Only put it inside the `signUp` handler.